# Create UI tree view

Tags: gratis, library, c#, unity

I want a tree view to appear in the program interface in Unity. I have tree data in my program insomuch that I can print this data in a UI text. However, I want to build a tree view for user in a panel (like buttons; when we press it shows us subcategories of this node). My question is if there is any simple way to implement this.

What I want to do is [this](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/tree-view-65364) but that's paid.